# How to trigger jquery event handler only if events happened in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following case. I'm using Bootstrap tabs with MarionetteJS. Whenever a tab click event is fired, I would like to call my handler only after show.bs.tab event is fired for this tab. I do not want to fire my handler if only shown.bs.tab event is fired, since ocassionally I show specific tabs programmatically by calling tab('show') method.

So basically only call handler after the following sequence of events ***click -> shown.bs.tab***

The way I got it to work is the following:

```
var clicked = false;
this.$el.on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
    clicked = true;
});

this.$el.on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
    if (clicked === true) {
        var moduleId = $(this).attr("data-module");
        App.vent.trigger("resultTabClicked", {
            module: moduleId
        });
    }
    clicked = false;
});
```

This is a far cry from an elegant solution is there a better way to achieve this? Perhaps with promises?

Comment: I don't know MarionetteJS, but why you can't attach the handler directly to the `click` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid global variables you could attach data to the element itself.

```
this.$el.on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

And then

```
if ($(this).data('clicked') === true) {
   ...
}
```

.data() is a jQuery method by the way but you can attach the status anyway you see fit

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the `handler` to both events and then use `event.type` and `event.timeStamp` to keep track of the order in which the events have happened. In the common handler, the event with the highest `timestamp` happened last; this should help determine when you've struck the right order so as to fire the desired code. See the concept verification demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  var times = {click:0,mouseenter:0,mouseleave:0};
  $('div.mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(e) {
    times[e.type] = e.timeStamp;
    $('div.out').text( JSON.stringify( times ) );
  });
});
```

```css
div
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">hover or click HIRE</div>
<div class="out"></div>
```